# How do I properly convert a photo URL to a Uint8List? and assign that variable to another Uint8List?

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I am working on a social media application for a project and am trying to add the functionality for editing already existing posts made by the currently signed in user. Part of this process involves getting the old post objects from Cloud Firestore and assigning them to variables which will be changed by the user before uploading the post back to the database.

The issue comes about when I try to pass the old post photo to the new photo variable. Because of the way my partner did his side of the code, I need to take the URL of the photo in Firebase Cloud Storage (which was already converted from an Uint8List? variable to URL), convert it back into a Uint8List? object, and assign the Uint8List? object to the _file variable, which is what the user will change when they choose a different photo. I appear to have (mostly) the proper code to do this, however, whenever I try to test this screen, I receive either a "Null check operator used on null value" error or a typecast error when assigning the file variable. What needs to be changed in order to prevent both of these errors from occurring? To be clear, I need to pass in the photo, among other properties, from the old post so that the current user knows what they are actually editing. Once I have these two errors solved, I expect the correct information to be displayed on the screen.

Below is the code responsible for this functionality. Note that a lot of irrelevant stuff was cut from it before posting here:

```dart
class EditPostPage extends StatefulWidget {
  EditPostPage({Key? key, required this.selectedPost}) : super(key: key);

  static Route routeMessage(Post post) => MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => EditPostPage(
            selectedPost: post,
          ));

  final Post selectedPost;

  @override
  _EditPostScreenState createState() => _EditPostScreenState();
}

class _EditPostScreenState extends State<EditPostPage> {
  // Variable which will be set to an actual photo file within the SelectImage function.
  Uint8List? _file;
  // The boolean indicating if the program is either loading or running.
  bool isLoading = false;
  // The text controller for the post's description.
  final TextEditingController _descriptionController = TextEditingController();
  // The text controller for the post's tags.
  final TextEditingController _tagsController = TextEditingController();
  // Initialize the tagList.
  List<dynamic> tagList = [];

  // Function to save the user created post in Firestore, thus publishing it on the home page. Its parameters are the userID of the user making the post,
  //    the username of the user making the post, and the profile picture of the user making the post.
  void postImage(String postID, DateTime datePublished, dynamic likes, String uid, String username, String profImage) async {
    // While posting the image, set isLoading to true to indicate that the app is working on uploading the post.
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    try {
      String res = await FireStoreMethods().updatePost(
          postID,
          // TODO: Match with the new user inputs.
          _descriptionController.text,
          // TODO: Match with the new user inputs.
          _file!,
          datePublished,
          likes,
          uid,
          username,
          profImage,
          // TODO: Match with the new user inputs.
          tagList);
      // If updatePost returns "success"...
      if (res == "success") {
        // Set isLoading back to false to continue the application.
        setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
        });
        // Show a notification indicating that the post was published.
        showSnackBar(
          context,
          'Posted!',
        );
        // Call clearImage() to dispose of the photo file contained in the _file variable.
        clearImage();
        // Call the .clear() function on the tagList to clean up the contained tags.
        tagList.clear();
        // If the result from uploadPost is not "success"...
      } else {
        // Show a notification with the relevant return value, which should be an error code of some kind.
        showSnackBar(context, res);
      }
      // If the try block fails, catch the error...
    } catch (err) {
      // Set isLoading back to false.
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
      // Show a notification with the relevant error that has occurred.
      showSnackBar(
        context,
        err.toString(),
      );
    }
  }

  // Function which converts a URL photo into a Uint8List object.
  Future<Uint8List?> generateBytesFromURL(String URL, String postID) async {
    final cloudImage = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('posts').child(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid.toString()).child(postID);
    const oneMegabyte = 1024 * 1024;
    Uint8List? data = await cloudImage.getData(oneMegabyte);
    return data;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Create a UserProvider object in order to get the current user's information later.
    final UserProvider userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);
    // Create a FocusNode object to provide to the TagEditor.
    final FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();

    // TODO: Set the necessary variables to the original post's. Untested.
    String originalPostID = widget.selectedPost.postId;
    String oldDescription = widget.selectedPost.description;
    String originalPhotoURL = widget.selectedPost.postUrl;
    DateTime originalDatePublished = widget.selectedPost.datePublished;
    dynamic originalLikes = widget.selectedPost.likes;
    List<dynamic> originalTagList = widget.selectedPost.tags;

    _descriptionController.text = oldDescription;
    // This is where the typeCast error occurs.
    _file = generateBytesFromURL(originalPhotoURL, originalPostID);
    tagList = originalTagList;

    return Scaffold(
      // Start creating the AppBar of the Scaffold object.
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor,
        // Create an IconButton object for the back button.
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          // TODO: Change clearImage to resetImage.
          onPressed: clearImage,
        ),
        // Create the title of the AppBar.
        title: const Text(
          'Edit Post',
        ),
        // Set whether or not the title should be centered.
        centerTitle: true,
        // Add any widgets necessary.
        actions: <Widget>[
          // Create a TextButton object which will act as our "Finish" button.
          TextButton(
            // TODO: Change the current postImage function call to update the original post rather than create a new one.
            // Upon pressing the "Finish" button, call the postImage function, providing the necessary information for its parameters.
            onPressed: () => postImage(originalPostID, originalDatePublished, originalLikes, userProvider.getUser.uid, userProvider.getUser.username, userProvider.getUser.photoUrl),
            // Set the text of the button to the word "Finish".
            child: const Text(
              "Finish",
              // Set the style of the button's text using a TextStyle object.
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16.0),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      // Create the body of the Scaffold, starting with a Column object.
      body: Column(
        // Start the widget tree for the Column.
        children: <Widget>[
          // If the isLoading variable is true...
          isLoading
              // Return a LinearProgressIndicator, or a loading widget.
              ? const LinearProgressIndicator()
              // If the isLoading variable is false...
              :
              // Start the column with a divider.
              const Divider(),
          // Create the post elements using a row.
          Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  // Create the widget to display the selected photo.
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 250.0,
                    width: 250.0,
                    child: AspectRatio(
                      //aspectRatio: 487 / 451,
                      aspectRatio: 500 / 250,
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          alignment: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
                          // This is where the null check error occurs.
                          image: MemoryImage(_file!),
                        )),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              // Button to upload another image.
              IconButton(onPressed: () => _selectImage(context), icon: const Icon(Icons.upload)),
              // Place a divider under the photo, description, and upload icon, separating the two from the TagEditor.
              const Divider(),
            ],
          ),
          const Divider(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Typecast error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMfot.jpg)

[(1) Null check operator error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4P1CQ.png)

[(2) Null check operator error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edCxK.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple wrong things in your code:

1. you should not be doing any async operations in the `build()` method. As a rule of thumb, only use the build method to draw your widgets.
2. you should use the initState and didChangeDependencies to prepare async loading when your widget is created. As a rule of thumb, do not include any methods that call setState in initState -> put them in didChangeDependencies. Those two methods get called before build() does.
3. too many comments, consider changing your variable names to be descriptive names, instead of using so many comments. For example, _descriptionController can be _postDescriptionController, then the comment you have on the line above it can be nuked.
4. setState rebuilds your entire widget's build tree -> consider using ValueNotifier for your _file variable and ValueListenableBuilder widget. Lots of resources online on how to use these.

I took a stab at fixing some if the problems that you had, but I didn't run it, so you might still have some issues. Good luck!

```
class EditPostPage extends StatefulWidget {
  EditPostPage({Key? key, required this.selectedPost}) : super(key: key);

  static Route routeMessage(Post post) => MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => EditPostPage(
            selectedPost: post,
          ));

  final Post selectedPost;

  @override
  _EditPostScreenState createState() => _EditPostScreenState();
}

class _EditPostScreenState extends State<EditPostPage> {
  // Variable which will be set to an actual photo file within the SelectImage function.
  Uint8List? _file;
  // The boolean indicating if the program is either loading or running.
  bool isLoading = false;
  // The text controller for the post's description.
  final TextEditingController _descriptionController = TextEditingController();
  // The text controller for the post's tags.
  final TextEditingController _tagsController = TextEditingController();
  // Initialize the tagList.
  List<dynamic> tagList = [];

  late final UserProvider userProvider;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Create a UserProvider object in order to get the current user's information later.
    userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() async {
    super.didChangeDependencies();

    // TODO: Set the necessary variables to the original post's. Untested.
    String originalPostID = widget.selectedPost.postId;
    String oldDescription = widget.selectedPost.description;
    String originalPhotoURL = widget.selectedPost.postUrl;
    DateTime originalDatePublished = widget.selectedPost.datePublished;
    dynamic originalLikes = widget.selectedPost.likes;
    List<dynamic> originalTagList = widget.selectedPost.tags;

    _descriptionController.text = oldDescription;
    // This is where the typeCast error occurs.
    tagList = originalTagList;

    _file = await generateBytesFromURL(originalPhotoURL, originalPostID);

    setState({})
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    _descriptionController.dispose();
    _tagsController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }


  // Function to save the user created post in Firestore, thus publishing it on the home page. Its parameters are the userID of the user making the post,
  //    the username of the user making the post, and the profile picture of the user making the post.
  void postImage(String postID, DateTime datePublished, dynamic likes, String uid, String username, String profImage) async {
    // While posting the image, set isLoading to true to indicate that the app is working on uploading the post.
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    if (_file == null) {
      return;
    }
    try {
      String res = await FireStoreMethods().updatePost(
          postID,
          // TODO: Match with the new user inputs.
          _descriptionController.text,
          // TODO: Match with the new user inputs.
          _file!,
          datePublished,
          likes,
          uid,
          username,
          profImage,
          // TODO: Match with the new user inputs.
          tagList);
      // If updatePost returns "success"...
      if (res == "success") {
        // Set isLoading back to false to continue the application.
        setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
        });
        // Show a notification indicating that the post was published.
        showSnackBar(
          context,
          'Posted!',
        );
        // Call clearImage() to dispose of the photo file contained in the _file variable.
        clearImage();
        // Call the .clear() function on the tagList to clean up the contained tags.
        tagList.clear();
        // If the result from uploadPost is not "success"...
      } else {
        // Show a notification with the relevant return value, which should be an error code of some kind.
        showSnackBar(context, res);
      }
      // If the try block fails, catch the error...
    } catch (err) {
      // Set isLoading back to false.
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
      // Show a notification with the relevant error that has occurred.
      showSnackBar(
        context,
        err.toString(),
      );
    }
  }

  // Function which converts a URL photo into a Uint8List object.
  Future<Uint8List?> generateBytesFromURL(String URL, String postID) async {
    final cloudImage = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('posts').child(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid.toString()).child(postID);
    const oneMegabyte = 1024 * 1024;
    Uint8List? data = await cloudImage.getData(oneMegabyte);
    return data;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      // Start creating the AppBar of the Scaffold object.
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor,
        // Create an IconButton object for the back button.
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          // TODO: Change clearImage to resetImage.
          onPressed: clearImage,
        ),
        // Create the title of the AppBar.
        title: const Text(
          'Edit Post',
        ),
        // Set whether or not the title should be centered.
        centerTitle: true,
        // Add any widgets necessary.
        actions: <Widget>[
          // Create a TextButton object which will act as our "Finish" button.
          TextButton(
            // TODO: Change the current postImage function call to update the original post rather than create a new one.
            // Upon pressing the "Finish" button, call the postImage function, providing the necessary information for its parameters.
            onPressed: () => postImage(originalPostID, originalDatePublished, originalLikes, userProvider.getUser.uid, userProvider.getUser.username, userProvider.getUser.photoUrl),
            // Set the text of the button to the word "Finish".
            child: const Text(
              "Finish",
              // Set the style of the button's text using a TextStyle object.
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16.0),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      // Create the body of the Scaffold, starting with a Column object.
      body: Column(
        // Start the widget tree for the Column.
        children: <Widget>[
          // If the isLoading variable is true...
          isLoading
              // Return a LinearProgressIndicator, or a loading widget.
              ? const LinearProgressIndicator()
              // If the isLoading variable is false...
              :
              // Start the column with a divider.
              const Divider(),
          // Create the post elements using a row.
          Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  // Create the widget to display the selected photo.
                  _file == null ? Text("Loading...") : SizedBox(
                    height: 250.0,
                    width: 250.0,
                    child: AspectRatio(
                      //aspectRatio: 487 / 451,
                      aspectRatio: 500 / 250,
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          alignment: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
                          // This is where the null check error occurs.
                          image: MemoryImage(_file!),
                        )),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              // Button to upload another image.
              IconButton(onPressed: () => _selectImage(context), icon: const Icon(Icons.upload)),
              // Place a divider under the photo, description, and upload icon, separating the two from the TagEditor.
              const Divider(),
            ],
          ),
          const Divider(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```